# My Windows laptop wants to repair my phone, but my phone is happy

Tags: external-sd, windows

When I initiate a USB mount of my phone, Windows 7 tells me the disk is going bad and wants to know if I want to rapair it (Motorola Droid 1; FRG22D if that matters). I am assuming this is a problem between the two disk systems talking to each other (like when you try to mount any EXT4 partition with Windows).

A) Is it really in need of repair? If so, should Windows be doing it? (Windows has no actual, practical problems with R/W of the drive and the phone is not reporting any issues or taking too long when remounting the SD card)

B) If Windows is just spitting up irrelevant error messages, how should I mount to disable the error message? Is this is just an annoyance anyone else has encountered?

Comment: FWIW, I have the same phone/OS as you, and I've never seen that message.

Comment: Tough problem to search for... google thinks I want to repair windows 7.

Comment: I'd say it likely is corrupt. The mounted storage is just the FAT32 partition on your memory card -- none of the linux partitions are mounted by default, unless you've got an aftermarket Apps2SD setup. As long as we're talking about your FAT32 partition, GAThrawn's answer below is correction.

Comment: @sai I had apps2sd setup while I was rooted, but I have had the problem before, during, and after (I got my phone replaced) rooting. The primary constant is the SD card. Thanks for clarifying that the FAT partition is the only one to mount; did not know that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had that on my old HTC Magic a couple of times, it is supposedly down to not properly doing the Eject Disk bit in Windows and Unmount drive bit on the phone before unplugging it.

After it had annoyed me enough times by asking me to repair the disk every time, I unplugged the micro-SD card from my phone, put it in a USB SD card reader, plugged that straight into the PC and let Windows run the repair. This time the repair completed successfully, and after plugging the SD back into the phone I didn't have any more problems with it (for a few months at least).

Comment: I am going to have to clone and give that a shot this weekend thanks!