# Should I let Windows "Fix" my SD card?

Tags: sd-card, windows

Windows is popping up a message that my card may have been improperly ejected and is offering to fix it. Should I let it?

Comment: Possibly related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2346/my-windows-laptop-wants-to-repair-my-phone-but-my-phone-is-happy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your card working? Can you put it back in your phone and access it? If yes, don't "fix" it.