# How to fix a damaged sd card?

Tags: external-sd, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“SD card is damaged - You may have to reformat.” How do I fix this problem?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3963/sd-card-is-damaged-you-may-have-to-reformat-how-do-i-fix-this-problem)

I made my SD card available as mass storage, copied one file from the SD card, unmounted the card from OSX (inside OSX) and then .. I am not 100% if I unmounted the card in mobile or it was already damaged at this point.

I tried to reboot the phone but it doesn't help. Removed the card, put back and turned on again. Didn't help either.

Do I have to reformat the card and lose all data on it?

---

HTC Desire + CM 7 RC2 + Kingston 16GB Type 4

Comment: one more question, any idea how come the card was demaged? How can I prevent it so it will not happen again?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to recover files before you format it, but yes you will have to format it.  See this question for various methods of SD card recovery: [Data Recovery - How to Restore Deleted / Formatted Files on HD Micro SD Card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7069/data-recovery-how-to-restore-deleted-formatted-files-on-hd-micro-sd-card)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a card reader, try fsck-ing it. I'm not sure if it is possible do an fsck through Android, though if you don't have a card reader, you might want to try that.