# Micro SD card physically damaged?

Tags: external-sd, system-freeze, formatting

it seems to me that my sd card is damaged so I wiped/erased it from android few times but it did not help.

Right now what happens is that if the card is present the phone freezes (not always) at the same time. SO it seems to me that the card is physically damaged.

Can I somehow find out **if the card is damaged**? The best from my phone.

Is there any **low lever format of micro SD cards** that might help in such case? Mark bad blocks so something similar?

---

HTC Desire + CM 7 RC2 + Kingston 16GB Type 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried formatting your SD Card in a dedicated reader, as opposed to doing it directly on the phone?

Most phones (and even most laptops' built-in SD Card readers) have problems writing SD Card partitions.  I usually format my SD Cards in a stand-alone card reader hooked up to my PC via USB.  Also, it's probably worth [re-partitioning](http://geeks.pirillo.com/profiles/blogs/how-to-partition-an-sd-card) it with Partition Editor from Ubuntu LiveCD.

Comment: I haven't tried dedicated card reader, I will try one. Actually the card became "faulty" few days/weeks after I partitioned it using my built-in reader in my notebook under Win7.

Comment: why do you think it is good idea to partition the card? I am not sure if it's a good to use ext on my card.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting creating an extra Ext partition, I meant only re-creating the existing Fat/Fat32 partition.

Comment: what would 're-creating' do?

Comment: By deleting an existing partition and creating a new one, you would be overwriting the SD Card's partition tables, in case that is where the corruption occurred. Again, this is just something else to try in case re-formatting in a stand-alone reader doesn't resolve the problem you're having.

Comment: well I did re-partitioning via external reading and everything works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best way to test it is to write data to all of it and see if one of the following occurs:

1. The write fails
2. The data/files don't show when you look for them
3. The data cannot be read
4. The data is corrupt

You can't flag sectors as bad as far as I'm aware, though, due to the FAT filesystem of SD cards.

Comment: what if nothing of above happens? my android freezes because of this card. Was ok for 6 months but now ...

Comment: is there any difference to do the testing under android or on my laptop?

Comment: It's probably much easier to do it on your laptop.  If the only problem seems to be that it's the phone, I recommend doing a factory reset and seeing if it still happens.  Or trying a different SD card, if you have access to one.

Comment: I already tried factory reset and wiped all I could. It didn't help. I can try my  second card and adapter so I can insert micro sd card in my notebook in few days ...